# Bootstrap 3 Modal Event (Hidden.Bs.Modal) Keeps Repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have 6 images that load in different 6 different modal windows and they each have a next button and also a close button in them. The next button works with the following jquery code:

```
    $('#nextModal12').click(function() {
        $('#featuresModal1').modal('hide');
        $('#featuresModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#featuresModal2').modal('show');
            document.getElementById('#featuresModal1').style.display="none";
        });
    });

    $('#nextModal23').click(function() {
        $('#featuresModal2').modal('hide');     
        $('#featuresModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#featuresModal3').modal('show');
            document.getElementById('#featuresModal2').style.display="none";                            
        });
    });
```

However, the problem is: Even when I **close**/**hide** the first modal ('#nextModal12') by clicking the CLOSE button instead of the next, the second modal appears.

I believe this is because the hidden.bs.modal function is picked up and called again even when I'm not clicking the next button. **How do I prevent the script from picking up the hidden.bs.modal function indiscriminately?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try use **.one** function instead of **.on**. When you use .on() your callback would be repeating again and again, beacuse you bind it again for each click;

```
$('#nextModal12').click(function() {
    $('#featuresModal1').modal('hide');
    $('#featuresModal1').one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#featuresModal2').modal('show');
    });
});

$('#nextModal23').click(function() {
    $('#featuresModal2').modal('hide');     
    $('#featuresModal2').one('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#featuresModal3').modal('show');                          
    });
});
```

Comment: not at all. don't you want to check it as right answer!

Comment: Yes I just did, had to wait for the time to be up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bind `hidden.bs.modal` again and again on modal click, just bind it once like,

```
$('#nextModal12').click(function() {
    $('#featuresModal1').modal('hide');
});
 $('#featuresModal1').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#featuresModal2').modal('show');
    $(this).hide();// you can use hide function
});

$('#nextModal23').click(function() {
    $('#featuresModal2').modal('hide');     
});   
$('#featuresModal2').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#featuresModal3').modal('show');
    $(this).hide(); 
});
```

**Alternatively,** you can try

```
$('#nextModal12').click(function() {
    $('#featuresModal1').modal('hide'); // hide first
    $('#featuresModal2').modal('show'); // show second
});

$('#nextModal23').click(function() {
    $('#featuresModal2').modal('hide');
    $('#featuresModal3').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: It's the same. When I click on the close button (not the next button), the second modal still pops up!

Comment: I mean the outcome is the same*

Comment: Try my Alternative answer.

Comment: Thanks Rohan, I have tried your method previously but it caused a scrolling bug in the modal, therefore I had to use event triggers to implement this feature. Mehmet's answer above is the fix that I needed.