# Block a javascript call till modal exits

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing a simple chrome extension to upload and share files over dropbox. My desired work flow is:

```
1. Select file to upload.
2. Click upload button.
3. A bootstrap modal opens up asking for email ids to share the file with.
4. Once the user has submitted email id in the modal dialogue box and saved it then
the upload function should be called.
```

Currently what happens is that modal shows up but the upload function is also called in the background, how can I block that until user has sucessfully submitted the input.

**EDIT:**

```
function startUpload()
{
    $('#emailModal').modal({backdrop: 'static'});
    //rest of the code to upload file via ajax call which needs to be
    //stoppped from executing till modal has successfully submitted or exited
}
```

Comment: What did you try yet? Can you provide some code?

Comment: In Javascript, you don't "block" executing code.   Because browser Javascript is single-threaded, blocking or looping would prevent any other code from running,including your modal.  Usually, you will structure these kinds of issues with a callback that gets called when the upload is done.

Comment: @SebastianNette I have added the tried code in the edit.

Answer (score 2):

The bootstrap modal has events you can watch for.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

**hidden.bs.modal** This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

This will fire when the modal is completely gone.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
});
```

Something else you can do is to setup your method that's doing the work to close the modal. So remove **data-dismiss="modal"** from the modal button and watch for a click event, run your upload stuff, then close the modal with **$('#myModal').modal('hide');**

Comment: thanks, this is working as expected but a little unexpected, I have an if else block within the `function(e){}` thing which gets executed twice sometimes. why is it so

Comment: Make sure you're not calling the code more than once. Also, you may need to use e.preventDefault(); so that the default action of the button is captured.

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: please have a look at my code here: http://codeshare.io/l3OLp  The `startUpload()` function is called only once but the `hidden.bs.modal` works perfectly only on the first run after page load, afterwhich it executes more than once on trying to upload next time

Comment: Okay an interesting thing I found, the number of repeitions after each try increments by 1, which means there is something that is persisting and triggering the `hidden.bs.modal` event continuously but I am unable to figure out possible reasons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27792795/bootstrap-3-modal-event-hidden-bs-modal-keeps-repeating solved my problem.

Comment: You need to use **one()** if you're running StartUpload more than once. Each time you run it you're adding on.